# Installing PostgreSQL on FreeBSD (with ports)

Tags: postgresql, freebsd, installation

Hey everyone, I am trying to install (using ports) PostgreSQL on a virtual server, running FreeBSD. My one question is this:

Which of the following should I install?

```
 postgresql-contrib
 postgresql-docs
 postgresql-jdbc
 postgresql-libpgeasy
 postgresql-libpq++
 postgresql-libpqxx
 postgresql-odbc
 postgresql-pllua
 postgresql-plproxy
 postgresql-plpython
 postgresql-plruby
 postgresql-pltcl
 postgresql-relay
 postgresql-tcltk
 postgresql73-client
 postgresql73-server
 postgresql74-client
 postgresql74-server
 postgresql80-client
 postgresql80-server
 postgresql81-client
 postgresql81-server
 postgresql82-client
 postgresql82-server
 postgresql83-client
 postgresql83-server
```

Thanks...

Comment: You need to do a portsnap since you are missing postgresql84.

Comment: DEFINITELY update your ports tree and use the postgresql84 ports. Many wonderful improvements over previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume that the `postgresql83-` packages are the most up-to-date PostgreSQL packages available. So, install postgresql83-client and postgresql83-server.

Comment: Do I have to install one before the other?

Comment: Just install them at the same time. It really shouldn't matter, though.

Comment: The order you install these in doesn't matter, but if you want something like what you would get from a postgres source installation you want both.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want, no?  If you want the server, use postgresql83-server.

Answer (score 0):

databases/postgresql84-server is the latest stable version in ports, so you probably want to go for it. However, as voretaq7 points out, you probably want to run 'portsnap fetch && portsnap update'  to get your ports-tree up to date.